# Transaction Multi Collection MongoDB by Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to make a transaction of MongoDB by Mongoose.
Mongoose version is ^5.8.9
Here is code to explain more details.

Below is my question.

1. how to match session on each collection. because I looking forward to use a session for each collection. however i fail to find a solution.
2. If one collection of User or Score, Transaction should be rollback and change work never to apply collection.

Is it possible ?

```
// here is just sample. it is not able to run by below the code

const session = await User.startSession();
await session.startTransaction();

try {
   const user = await User.create(object);
   const score = await Score.updateOne({userId : user._id }, {score : { $inc :5 }} );
   // if one of User or Score will be failed, transaction should be rollback. 
   await session.commitTransaction();
} catch(e) {
   console.log(e)
   await session.abortTransaction();
} finally {
   await session.endSession();
}
```

Comment: What does mongoose's documentation say about transactions?

Comment: I meant 
IF one of document work of User or Score fail, all transaction work should be roll back (no apply any changed to document (collection) sorry my poor explain question